# What is causing this difference between my Ruby on Rails console output and my Firebug console output when using a Ruby date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Can anyone explain the difference between the Ruby on Rails console output and the Firebug console output?

event_controller.rb

```
def list_events
    @days[1][:date] = (((Date.new(2010, 8, 6)) + 1).to_s)
end
```

list_events.html.erb

```
<% @days.each_with_index do |day, i| %>
    <% p day[:date] %>; //RoR console
    console.log(<%= day[:date] %>); //Firebug console
<% end %>
```

Ruby on Rails console output:

```
"2010-08-07"
```

Firebug console output:

```
1995
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript statement that is actually being executed is this:

```
console.log(2010-08-07);
```

—This is evaluated as 2010 minus 8 minus 7, which equals...1995! You have to make sure that the console log statement receives a string. Try this instead:

```
console.log("<%= day[:date] %>");
```

Comment: definitely the Principle of Least Surprise!